# facebook login asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I'm using asp.net/vb.net for developing a web application and we have a user accounts and login etc.

We would like to add "login with Facebook" to the website but the problem after the Facebook dialog show and the user click allow what Facebook will return? Their documentation don't show what next should be done. I've choosed that the app will return query string but I don't see them or maybe I don't know how to receive them. I've put their button code and it works fine and it call the dialog.

My question is what are the next step sorry I've read the documentation on their site but It don't show what to do next please direct me or guide me to the right documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I was in the exact same situation as you a few weeks back. I found a really good article on using a C# REST library called Hammock. Check out the tutorial here: http://www2.suddenelfilio.net/2010/09/08/connect-to-facebook-using-asp-net-facebook-graph-api-hammock/

Using Hammock, you can get the information you require from Facebook into your own application.

Comment: there is also the facebook c# sdK which is much easier to use and understand. Thanks for your help.